# Fade-In css latency

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

Hello so im trying to fade in to cotainers that are replaced with data fetched with flask
HTML + CSS code

```
<img class="imgContainer" onload="this.style.opacity=1" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_' ~ player1.username ~ '_.png') }}"/>

.imgContainer {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
```

}

This is how I "fade in my container"
And this is how I fade it out:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/vote",
        type : "POST",
        data : { "winner" : "1", "player1" : player1, "player2" : player2 },
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) {
            $("#container").fadeOut()
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#container").replaceWith(data);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

My problem at the moment is that it doesnet fade in both containers at the same time and there is a latency between them.
What is the best way to fix that, and make them appear at the same time?

Comment: Your example code doesn't reference the html you've provided. Firstly, jQuery's fadeOut does not need transition to be set in css. You can edit the speed and easing as extra parameters. Second. If you're doing multiple asynchronous calls. They will fire the success callback at different times.

Answer (score 1):

Onload events executed after the element has been loaded. Maybe your images doesn't load the same time, that's why your fades are not match. I would try to wrap the images into a div if that's possible and set onload on it, or use @keyframes instead of onload (I'm not sure about that tho).